# How to move a div to the last child in an element with multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you move an element to the last child?

```
<div class="mail-email-block">
  <div class="email-raw">
    <div class="single-data-item">
      <div class="line_wrap"></div>
      <div class="line_wrap"></div>
      <div class="line_wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-data-item">
      <div class="line_wrap"></div>
      <div class="line_wrap"></div>
      <div class="line_wrap"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="email-block">
    stuff
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mail-email-block">
  <div class="email-raw">
    <div class="single-data-item">
      <div class="line_wrap"></div>
      <div class="line_wrap"></div>
      <div class="line_wrap"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="email-block">
    stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find a way to move `.email-block` to the inside of the last child of `.single-data-item` for each element. I've been having problems that take all of '.email-block` and moves them to the first element. Something that looks like this:

```
<div class="email-raw">
   <div class="single-data-item">
     <div class="line_wrap"></div>
     <div class="line_wrap"></div>
     <div class="line_wrap"></div>
     <div class="email-block"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way using `.each()` and `.appendTo()`:

```js
$('.mail-email-block').each(function(){
  $(this).find('.email-block').appendTo($(this).find('.single-data-item'));
});
```

```css
.email-raw, .single-data-item{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mail-email-block">
  <div class="email-raw">
    <div class="single-data-item">
      <div class="line_wrap">11</div>
      <div class="line_wrap">11</div>
      <div class="line_wrap">11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-data-item">
      <div class="line_wrap">22</div>
      <div class="line_wrap">22</div>
      <div class="line_wrap">22</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="email-block">
    stuff 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mail-email-block">
  <div class="email-raw">
    <div class="single-data-item">
      <div class="line_wrap">33</div>
      <div class="line_wrap">33</div>
      <div class="line_wrap">33</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="email-block">
    stuff 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but your code puts on all and I just want it on the last item. I solved it by adding `::last-child`: `$('.mail-email-block').each(function(){
  $(this).find('.email-block').appendTo($(this).find('.single-data-item:last-child'));
});`

Answer (score 1):

I think just `appendChild()` will solve your problem.

```js
const singleDataItem = document.querySelector(".single-data-item"); //get the .single-data-item element
const emailBlock = document.querySelector(".email-block"); //get the .email-block element
singleDataItem.appendChild(emailBlock);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
let emailBlock = $('.email-block').detach();
$('.single-data-item .line_wrap').last().append(emailBlock);
```